# Remap keys on windows without running EXEs or admin

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, powershell, remapping

I work in an environment (Win10) where you are allowed to modify files in your user folder, but are not allowed admin or the ability to run any executable file. I am also not allowed to modify the registry. I am not allowed access to CMD, but I do have access to PowerShell (the latest version in constrained language mode, and PowerShell v2 in full language mode).  I want to do this with the existing hardware (laptop), rather than use my external keyboard.  How can I remap the keys to Colemak layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I remap the keys to the Colemak keyboard layout?

This cannot be done given the restrictions you describe.  You cannot use the layout in question without a third-party application, even if Windows 10 had a native Colemak keyboard layout, you don't have the permission required to change your keyboard layout.

Due to the restrictions you are under what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could find a hardware solution.

There are:

- Keyboards who's firmware you can edit.
- Keyboards who have on-board software, usually aimed at remapping keys.
- Mechanical keyboards that allow you to physically rearrange your keys.
- Custom printed keyboards

These guys kept coming up in my searches:

- TypeMatrix 2030 (Fn + F5)
- WASDv2
- WASD Code
- Kinesis advantage
- Vortex Pok3r

I even found a javascript tool, straight from colemak.com:
https://colemak.com/Converter

I think it's likely you could find a projection virtual keyboard you could reprogram and then use, too.

Comment: I already have a programmable keyboard, I just want to be able to use the laptop keyboard with Colemak as well as my external keyboard.

Comment: @Merlin04 I submitted an edit to the question, to note that hardware is an additional constraint.